# How to show more details in `seaborn.kdeplot()`?

Tags: seaborn, kernel-density, density-plot

I have a scatter plot on the left-hand side below, where there are lots of data points, and the figure on the right are corresponding density plot using `seaborn.kdeplot()`.  But unfortunately since the variance of the density is so large that `kdeplot` fails to capture many details in other low-density area (e.g. there is basically no information about the density distribution on the top right).

Does anyone have any ways to fix this issue?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: BTW unsolicited advice: it looks like you're using a circular colormap to show values between 0 and 2 * pi; make sure you set the colormap limits to include the full range.

Comment: @mwaskom Actually I am not working with the circular variables, they just happen to fall into [0, 2*pi].  Thanks for your advice though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `n_levels` parameter, i.e.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5), sharex=True, sharey=True)
x, y = np.random.normal(0, 1, (2, 1000))
axes[0].scatter(x, y, s=5, c=".1")
sns.kdeplot(x, y, n_levels=10, ax=axes[1])
sns.kdeplot(x, y, n_levels=30, ax=axes[2])
f.tight_layout()
```

[image]